# React JS - Prevent Parent onClick when clicked on child onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

Here is the jsx

When i click the **ROW** **myParentClick** is triggered but when i click on any child which is **myChildClick** **myChildClick2**

Then it triggers both the parent and child.

The Parent is triggered first and then the child

```
{myData?.map((item, index) => {
    return(
        <Row onClick={() => myParentClick(index)}>
            <Col>
                // some html tags
            </Col>

            <Col>
                // some html tags
            </Col>

            <Col>
                // React Bootstrap DropDown
                <DropDown>
                    <DropDown.Toggle>
                        // code
                    </DropDown.Toggle>
                    <DropDown.Menu>
                        <DropDown.Item onClick={() => myChildClick(index)}>
                            <p>some TEXT</p>
                        </DropDown.Item>
                    </DropDown.Menu>
                </DropDown>
            </Col>

            <Col onClick={() => myChildClick2(index)} >
                <p>some TEXT</p>
            </Col>

            <Col onClick={() => myChildClick3(index)} >
                <p>some TEXT</p>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    )
})}
```

I have tried, on child click e.stopPropagation(); which is not working

```
onClick={
    (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        myChildClick(index)
    }
}
```

How to Prevent Parent onClick when clicked on child onClick ?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-breeze-gg4l6?file=/src/App.js (check the console)

Comment: If possible share you code in a codesandbox.

Comment: got the problem, it is Dropdown.Toggle causing the issue. How to avoid ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
onClick={
    (e) => {
        if (e.defaultPrevented) return
        e.preventDefault()
        
        myChildClick(index)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i took your code and tried to reproduce your issue. for some reason your stopPropagation doesnt work for you, but when i tried it, it works fine:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mk1dcr